# Spark Kafka Structured Streaming integration with Apache Ignite

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, ignite

Right now there is no way by which i can save spark DataFrames in Apche Ignite. It will get included in Apache Ignite 2.2 version as mentioned here https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-3084. I am using Structured Streaming API of Apache Spark with Kafka for consuming data. I want to do some aggregations like average value for a particular column or min-max value on consumed data.

My question is whether i should use Spark SQL DataFrame API to do above mentioned aggregations or should i wait for Apache Ignite 2.2 version ? They have mentioned it in documentation that Ignite SQL is 100s faster than Spark SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it's up to you. You could go ahead with Spark now, then wait for DataFrames support in Ignite is ready, compare these two approaches and choose which fits your needs better.